# Any difference between t<'a> and 'a t in F#?

Tags: f#

Is there any difference in meaning between `t<'a>` and `'a t` in F#? Can they be used interchangeably even after declaration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no difference, and yes, they can be used interchangeably even after declaration.

But do note the [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/#consider-using-the-prefix-syntax-for-generics-foot-in-preference-to-postfix-syntax-t-foo-with-four-notable-exceptions-list-option-array-ref) recommendation (Section 4.2):

> Consider using the prefix syntax for generics (`Foo<T>`) in preference
>   to postfix syntax (`T Foo`), with  four notable exceptions (`list`,
>   `option`, `array`, `ref`).
>
> F# inherits both the postfix ML style of naming
>   generic types, e.g. “`int list`” as well as the prefix  .NET style, e.g.
>   “`list<int>`”.  You should prefer the .NET style, except for four
>   specific types.  For F#  lists, use the postfix form: “`int list`”
>   rather than “`list<int>`”.  For options, use the postfix form:  “`int option`”
>   rather than “`option<int>`”.  For arrays, use the syntactic name
>   “`int[]`” rather than  either “`int array`” or “`array<int>`”.  For `refs`,
>   use “`int ref`” rather than “`ref<int>`” or  “`Ref<int>`”. For all other
>   types, use the prefix form: “`HashSet<int>`”, “`Dictionary<string,int>`”, 
>   since this conforms to .NET standards

Also, you'll get a compiler warning if you use the ML-style generic parameter list notation, e.g. `('a,'b) t` vs. `t<'a,'b>`.

And while we're at it, note the following recommendation in [Section 3.1](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/#do-use-the-net-naming-and-capitalization-conventions-for-object-oriented-code-including-f-facing-libraries) of the same guide:

> Do use PascalCase for generic parameter names in public APIs,
>   including for F#-facing libraries. In particular, use names like T, U,
>   T1, T2 for arbitrary generic parameters, and when specific names  make
>   sense, then for F#-facing libraries use names like Key, Value, Arg
>   (but not e.g. TKey).

(though personally I tend to ignore this recommendation for F#-facing public libraries).

Answer (score 3):

No difference at all, is not sure this is worth a whole answer! I prefer the former especially when it comes to multiple type parameters (is that possible with the latter?).

Comment: Yes, you do `(string, float) Hashtbl.t` in OCaml.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `'a t` syntax is more idiomatic (it is used in almost all the MSDN examples and emitted by the compiler will generate that syntax for signature files)

There is a similar example for arrays

```
int[] , int array
```

The `'a t` syntax is also nicer for concrete parameters -

```
int list, List<int>
```

so some consistency argues for `'a t`

Answer (score 1):

I would say the difference is readability.  For one parameter the `'` syntax isn't overly confusing but when you get a list of them it becomes much easier to read the angle bracket version.