# What are the various ways that I can declare a type that operates on a generic type?

Tags: generics, syntax, f#

What are the various ways that I can declare a type that operates on a generic type?

I saw the following syntax:

```
// There's a generic type called Aggregate that will be operated on by the Id type
type 'Aggregate Id = Created of 'Aggregate
```

Is the syntax above an alternative way of making the following declaration?

```
// The Id type operates on a generic type called 'Aggregate
type Id<'Aggregate> = Created of 'Aggregate
```

I attempted to reference the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/). However, I did not see an example of an alternative technique.

Comment: Related (if not identical): [Any difference between t<'a> and 'a t in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10167359/467754)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know the first one is the **old** syntax taken from OCaml/ML.

Both are the same insofar as single parameter generics are concerned. Multi param generics like

```
type 'a 'b Id = ...
```

do not work. you will have to do

```
type ('a, 'b) Id = ...
```

I find that syntax very unfortunate as all .NET - interfacing code and documentation will always use the C# syntax

```
type Id<'a, 'b> = ...
```

And VSCode/Ionide (just in case you use them) also uses the C# notation. I personally also switched to C# Notation for single params generics as well simply to have the same notation everywhere

Comment: I must say, I really like how `string list` reads like English.

Comment: As I am a sucker for consistency and multi param generics ... I feel differently ;-)